# Simulated gravity equations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, computational-physics, simulations, software

I'm working on a game that'll have a (I probably naively believe) simple gravity component and am looking for a couple of equations for the task.

> Given 1) a ball rolling from point A down (or up) a slope to point B, 2) the angle of the slope, 3) the distance to point B, 4) the current velocity of the ball (may be 0), 5) any other necessary variables that I can just make up values for (mass? friction?)...

I need to calculate X) the time it'll take the ball to reach point B, and Y) it's new velocity when it gets there (both to be plugged back into the equations to recompute for point C, and so on.

Also need to deal with the possibility that a ball rolling up a slope may not have the momentum to reach point B, and in such case would need to know X) the time it would take to return to point A, and Y) it's velocity when it gets there.

It's not necessary for the computed values to be technically accurate. The results merely need to appear believable to a casual observer. Therefore, a less computationally expensive equation would be preferred over a more accurate one.

Any suggestions? Anything important that I've overlooked?

Comment: Might be useful to know what language you're writing in just in case it's relevant to someone's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, it seems you need to build a simulation, where for each time step you compute the change in velocity and position. This will allow you to vary the conditions and not have to pre-compute the outcome of the trajectory over large time frames.

**Example 1** - Moving along a ramp

[image: pic]

The displacement $s$ and speed $v$ is modeled with the following differential equations

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \dot{s} & = v \\
  \dot{v} & = -m g \sin \theta
\end{aligned} $$

Using the simplest [numerical integration](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/euler-method-solving-differential-equation/) of taking Euler steps you have

```
function Euler(t,s,v,h)
% t : time
% s : distance
% v : speed
% h : time step
    a = -m*g*sin(θ)
    t = t + h
    s = s + h*v
    v = v + h*a
end
```

**Example 2** - The same as above but the angle $\theta$ changes with position $s$, like with a loop, or a ramp.

```
function Euler(t,s,v,h)
% t : time
% s : distance
% v : speed
% h : time step
    θ = calc_slope(s)
    a = -m*g*sin(θ)
    t = t + h
    s = s + h*v
    v = v + h*a
end
```

Comment: So, I think what you're saying is, if x is my target distance, start t & s in the above to 0, v is the current speed, and select a value for h that can be safely assumed to be a small enough that we'll have to loop through this enough times to get a reasonably accurate result. Then loop through the equation until s >= x. At that point, t will be about how long it took to go x and v will be the new speed.

Comment: Yep, running this on a spreadsheet, I seem to be getting reasonable values, once I figured out to use a positive slope for uphill runs and a negative slope for downhill runs, and that the slope should be expressed in radians (not degrees).  Pretty sure I can make this work. Thanks!